# BULK Methods are throwing "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" EF Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to use : https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-extensions
but durring processing im getting error:
**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'XXX', table 'XXX'; column does not allow nulls.**
And that's true, but i have configured dbcontext with this column makred as required:

```
            builder.Property(x => x.XXX)
                .HasColumnName("XXX")
                .IsRequired();
```

Method used is in that way

```
            await ImportDbContext.Set<ENTITY>()
                .BulkSynchronizeAsync(ENTITY, options =>
            {
                options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = entity => entity .XXX;
                options.SynchronizeKeepidentity = true;
            });
```

In logs i saw that extension creating own cache table where this column is marked as possible null... so propably this problem is here, extensions dont recognize that column should be notnull...
I have DbFirst approach.

Please help me with that case or maybe there is better extension to EF to Bulk operations.

Comment: Did you confirm the data being bulk inserted with `ENTITY` none of the objects have that property as null?

Answer (score 1):

As @DenisMicheal.k wrote in the comment section:

This error happens if one of the values of your property `XXX` is null.

For example, using the [BulkSynchronize in EF Core](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-synchronize) with the `ColumnString` marked as `NOT NULL` in the database will result in the same error:

```cs
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    List<EntitySimple> list = new List<EntitySimple>();
    list.Add(new EntitySimple { ColumnInt = 1, ColumnString = "a" });
    list.Add(new EntitySimple { ColumnInt = 2 });

    context.BulkSynchronize(list, options => options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => x.ColumnString);
}
```

The first entity could be inserted, but the second entity has `NULL` for the `ColumnString`, resulting in the following exception:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ColumnString', table 'LabEFECore70.dbo.EntitySimples'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.'
```